# Inheriting base class with recursive template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates

How to inherit Base class in recursive template class?
My requirement is something like this

```
Base <--- Param<> <--- Param<int> <---  Param<char,int> <---- Param<double,char,int>
```

I tried inheriting Base class in `class Param<> : public Base`
 In this case it is working for single template parameter, for multiple parameter throwing error. It is unable to inherit base members.

If it inherit in `class Param <TFirst,TRest...>: public Param<TRest...>, public Base`, then throwing ambiguity error. I think this can be avoided by using virtual keyword. But i am looking for some another approach.

Please help me with this issue,

```
class Base{
public:
    virtual void setData()=0;
protected:
    std::string data;
};

template<class ...Args>  // template class signature
class Param;

template<> //recursive template's  base class
class Param<> : public Base{
public:
    void setData(){
    }
};

template<class TFirst, class... TRest>
class Param <TFirst,TRest...>: public Param<TRest...>
{
public:
    void setData(){ // base class virtual function overriding
        data = "test data"; //access base class data throwing error.
        //do some other stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Your example [compiles for me as written](http://rextester.com/JCNVW5937), with or without deriving `Param<>` from `Base`. What specifically seems to be the problem?

Comment: I am not inheriting Base class in this example, which i need to do. I need to override setData() method and get access to Base class member variables inside class Param<TFrist, TRest...>

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think he's saying that `Param<int,int>` fails to compile. It would be better to explicitly add it to the question though, if that's the case

Comment: @SirGuy I am looking for an approach to inherit class Base to class Param.

Comment: @SirGuy Param<int, int> compiles for me. (Inheriting in Param<> from Base)

Comment: The example at the link has `Param<>` derived from `Base`, and instantiates `Param<double,char,int>` as per the question. It compiles successfully. I still fail to grasp the nature of the difficulty. Show a [mcve] together with the full and compete text of any error messages.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I have edited the code. Please try with this once.

Comment: To access a member of dependent base class (base class that depends on template parameters), use explicit qualification: `this->data = "test data";` or `Param::data = "test data";` or `Base::data = "test data";`.

Comment: `data = "test data";` should be `this->data = "test data";`

Comment: this->data is working, thanks a lot for your suggestions.